# Pl/sql full outer join among three tables

Tags: plsql

I have a complicated report to print. I have the following three tables:

- Table A contains full list of categories.
- Table B contains data pertaining to accounts in some categories for time period *a*.
- Table C contains data pertaining to accounts in some categories for time period *b*.

I need to print in Excel, column wise, the following:

- List of categories.
- Data category wise in *b*.

AccountCdata - accountBdata. ( for categories / accounts present both B and C)

- Data category wise in C.

I am trying to use full outer join to get report.

When I try this:

```sql
select * from  
A   
Full outer join   
B   
on catA= catB 

Full outer join
C
on CatC= catA
```

But this goes in loop taking super long to give result out. (My data contains millions of records.)

When I try

```sql
select * from 
A
Full outer join 
B 
on catA= catB
Full outer join 
C
on AccountC=accounts
```

But this doesn’t give list of accounts for categories present in c but absent in b.

Comment: Mysql does not support pl/sql, nor full outer join. Oracle, postgresql, and teradata support these. So, which platform do you use?

Comment: If the question is about a query then you probably want Oracle SQL, not the PL/SQL programming language.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. You need to provide table definitions (ddl), sample data, as text - **no images** and the expected results of that data.